# What can I do to protect myself if someone gets injured on my property?

Tags: utah, trees

I've got a large walnut tree in my backyard that I would like removed. I've been told that because walnut wood is valuable that if I post a local ad saying they can have the wood if they cut the tree down I might get a taker.

I assume this opens me up to personal injury liability, especially since powerlines run through the tree. I also cannot have my power company take the power lines down for this because they require an update to the receiver, and that would cost more than removing the tree with professionals.

Is there anything I can do to limit liability?

Comment: Hire a bonded professional.

Comment: Had an estimate from a bonded professional, it is a big tree. It will cost more than removing the tree is worth right now, and it is only getting bigger.

Comment: Probably cheaper than hiring a lawyer to write a liability release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Chapter 14, Part 2 of Utah Code](https://le.utah.gov/xcode/Title57/Chapter14/C57-14_1800010118000101.pdf), it states,

> an owner of land owes no duty of care
> to keep the land safe for entry or use by any person entering or using the land for any recreational
> purpose or to give warning of a dangerous condition, use, structure, or activity on the land.

But if the owner charges an admission fee for any recreational purposes or if there is wilful or malicious conduct involved, you are liable to face charges.

If you are hiring people to cut down your, tree it is your job to employ care and safety of the workers.